# Install Python Package for system wide use

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I wrote a Command Line Tool called "mcctl", written in Python, which needs root privileges to run.
The problem i am facing is when running `sudo pip install mcctl.whl`, the entry point scripts are installed into /usr/local/bin and not /usr/bin, which is not included on the sudo "secure_path", so the root user cannot access the entry point.

I did some research and found out that packages like pip are also installed in /usr/bin on my CentOS-System, but these point to /etc/alternatives via symlink. I am not sure why other package entry points do not install there.

So: what is the best solution to give the root user access to the App?

- Change the sudo secure_path?
- Somehow install the entry point into /usr/bin (although not easily possible to my knowledge)?
- Some other Solution?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: How did you install it btw? Via `pip` or plain `setup.py`?

Comment: I installed it via pip (pip install mcctl.whl), updated the question also...